# How to convert embedded image to mosaic thought illustrator JS scripting

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-scripting

I would like to convert an embedded image to a mosaic through a script since I need to iterate it a few hundred times. I've tried using `app.executeMenuCommand("Live PSAdapter_plugin_MscT");` but this prompts a dialog, making automation impossible. I've also tried using `app.doScript("toMosaic", "myActions", false);` but for some reason this seems to loop until stack overflow (this seems to be the case for any actions too).

I tired this:

```
doc.placedItems[0].embed();
app.executeMenuCommand("Live PSAdapter_plugin_MscT");
```

and also this (a working action in illustrator):

```
doc.placedItems[0].selected = true;
app.doScript ("toMosaic", "myActions", false);
```

Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To whom ever this may address, I figured out the cause of this strange behaviour. Running the script as an action with a key-bind (ex F1) does not seem to work properly with doScript() specifically. Running the script manually (selecting it under Scripts) works as intended however.